# How to map values from 2 datasets

Tags: python

I am trying to map values from different datasets, I got 2 datasets look like this:

df1:

| Pers. | A1 | A2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 500 | 1 | 2 |
| 501 | 3 | 1 |

df2:

| VAR | RES | MEAN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1 | "Yes" |
| A1 | 2 | "No" |
| A1 | 3 | "Maybe" |
| A2 | 1 | "answered" |
| A2 | 2 | "not answered" |

Was I want to achieve: I want Python code that looks at each column and each cell. Then, the value from table df1 should be taken (e.g., A1: 3). This value should then be looked up in table df2. So, if there is a 3 in column A1 of table df2, that 3 should be replaced with "Maybe" in the table. This should happen with all columns and values in df1.

I had thought about a mapping, but I don't know how to implement this mapping.

Comment: What have you tried thus far? How is this data stored?

Answer (score 1):

You can `.stack()` the `df1`, then merge values from `df2` into `df1` and `.pivot()` it back to original form:

```py
df1 = (
    df1.set_index("Pers.")
    .stack()
    .reset_index()
    .merge(df2, left_on=["level_1", 0], right_on=["VAR", "RES"])
    .pivot(index="Pers.", columns="VAR", values="MEAN")
    .rename_axis(index="Pers.", columns=None)
    .reset_index()
)
print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
   Pers.       A1              A2
0    500    "Yes"  "not answered"
1    501  "Maybe"      "answered"
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

# Sample dataframes
data1 = {'Pers.': [500, 501], 'A1': [1, 3], 'A2': [2, 1]}
data2 = {'VAR': ['A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A2'], 'RES': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2], 'MEAN': ['Yes', 'No', 'Maybe', 'answered', 'not answered']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

# Create a mapping dictionary from df2
mapping_dict = {}
for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    var = row['VAR']
    res = row['RES']
    mean = row['MEAN']
    mapping_dict[(var, res)] = mean

# Replace values in df1 using the mapping dictionary
for col in df1.columns[1:]:
    df1[col] = df1[col].map(lambda x: mapping_dict.get((col, x), x))

print(df1)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward approach is to iterate over the relevant columns of `df1` and replace each of them by applying a function that filters `df2` accordingly to look up the `MEAN` value:

```py
for col in df1.columns[1:]:
    df1[col] = df1[col].apply(lambda x: df2.query(
        "VAR == @col and RES == @x").MEAN.iloc[0])
```